# Error: This variant pattern is expected to have type prim1. The constructor Id does not belong to type prim1

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild

I don't have much experience with ocmal and the compiler error message isn't very helpful. I don't see any obvious problem with the code. I have the full code and the error message below. Thank you.

Full compiler error message:

```
File "compile.ml", 
     | Id(x) ->
       ^^
```

Error: This variant pattern is expected to have type prim1
       The constructor Id does not belong to type prim1

```
type reg =
    | EAX
    | ESP

type arg =
    | Const of int
    | Reg of reg
    | RegOffset of int * reg

type instruction =
    | IMov of arg * arg
    | IAdd of arg * arg
    | IRet

type prim1 =
    | Add1
    | Sub1

type expr =
    | Number of int
    | Prim1 of prim1 * expr
    | Let of (string * expr) list * expr
    | Id of string
```

```
let rec find (ls : (string * int) list) (x : string) =
    match ls with
    | [] -> None
    | (y,v)::rest ->
      if y = x then Some(v) else find rest x
```

```
let rec compile_env (p : expr) (stack_index : int) (env : (string * int) list) : instruction list =
    match p with
       | Number(n) -> [ IMov(Reg(EAX), Const(n)) ]
       | Prim1(op, e) ->
            match op with
            | Add1 -> (compile_env e stack_index env) @ [ IAdd(Reg(EAX), Const(1)) ]
            | Sub1 -> (compile_env e stack_index env) @ [ IAdd(Reg(EAX), Const(-1)) ]
       | Id(x) ->
            match find env x with
            | None -> failwith "%s not in scope" x
            | Some value -> [IMov(Reg(EAX), RegOffset(value, Reg(ESP)))]
       | Let(binds, body) ->
            match binds with
            | [] -> [] @ (compile_env body stack_index env)
            | (str, exp)::rest ->
                    let new_env = env @ [(str, -4*stack_index)] in
                    let eval_expr = (compile_env exp stack_index env) in
                    let eval_tail = (compile_env Let(rest, body) stack_index+1 new_env) in
                    eval_expr @ [IMov(RegOffset(-4*stack_index, Reg(ESP)), Reg(EAX))] @ eval_tail
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your problem is that you have nested `match` expressions. The difficulty is that the compiler is thinking that the next case of the outer `match` is in fact the next case of the inner `match`.

The solution is to parenthesize all of the the inner match expressions.

It should look something like this:

```
match p with
   | Number(n) -> [ IMov(Reg(EAX), Const(n)) ]
   | Prim1(op, e) ->
        (match op with
        | Add1 -> (compile_env e stack_index env) @ [ IAdd(Reg(EAX), Const(1)) ]
        | Sub1 -> (compile_env e stack_index env) @ [ IAdd(Reg(EAX), Const(-1)) ]
        )
    . . .
```

You need to do this for all of the nested `match` expressions (I see 3 of them).

Comment: Note: I think it's standard practice in a part of the community to use `begin match ... end` instead of parentheses here, to emulate languages whose `match` constructs are delimited by an `end` statement.

Comment: Right, good to know. One should follow the local coding conventions for sure. To OP: in expressions `begin` ... `end` in OCaml is completely equivalent to `(` ... `)`. E.g.: `3 * begin x + 1 end`.